# Unable to get Registration id using sns aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to send push notification from SNS to Mobile devices through Amazon Device Messaging (ADM)and GCM
 I tried with GCM but I got struck at getting registration id but it was showing that the amazon service is successfully deployed onto mobile and the same case with ADM
can any one suggest me in getting registration ID for my app

Comment: Need More information. Also read the documentation provided by AWS.